# Javascript Input Numbers Only Regular Expressions

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I have a RegEx validation that validates the field to be number only. However, what happens is the validation will only return true if the length of the string is more than 10 digits. But if less than 10, let's say 5, it returns false.

Here's my code:

```
function isNumeric(elem, helperMsg) {
    var numericExpression = /^[0-9]+$/;
    if (elem.value.match(numericExpression)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        alert(helperMsg);
        elem.focus();
        return false;
    }
}


function formValidator() {
    var phone = document.getElementById('home');
    if (isNumeric(phone, "Please enter a valid Australian House Phone Number")) {
        console.log("Passed phone number");
        if (isNumericPostal(postal, "Please enter a valid Postal Code of Australia it should be 4 digits only")) {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: what is the expected result? do you want to allow phone numbers with less than 10 digits or not?

Comment: I guess you want `/^[0-9]{10,}$/`

Comment: I just want numeric number that has a maximum of 13 digits. I am not requiring the number to be exactly 13 digits because it can be 9, 10, 11 etc.

Comment: Then it'll be `^\d{10,13}$`

Comment: Please, clarify the conditions for the regex to return true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are also mixing validation logic with UI logic in your isNumeric function. It's bad practice. `/^\d{10,13}$/.test(yourValue)` will return `true/false` - should be better in this case.

```
function isNumeric(val) {
    return /^\d{10,13}$/.test(val);
}

function formValidator() {
    var phone = document.getElementById('home');
    if (!isNumeric(phone.value)) {
       alert("Please enter a valid Australian House Phone Number");
       phone.focus();
       return false;
    }
    // do your other logic in similar manner
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks I would use this answer coz not only it solved my problem but saw a better way of doing it. The code was from mthe developer before, So I have to recode everything again.

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex `^(\d){9,13}$` instead

Comment: *it can be 9, 10, 11*

Comment: @stribizhev So, it will return true on 9,10,11 elements, too?

Comment: I do not know what OP needs, do not ask me. :) I stay away from answering such unclear questions, only comment.

Comment: @stribizhev sorry haha

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need:

```
/^[0-9]{0,13}$/
```

This will validate that the input string is between 0 to 13 digits length. So even if it 9, 10 digits it will pass.

If you have some minimum digit length as well, then change the `{0,13}` accordingly.

Between, http://www.regexr.com/ is a good site to create regex and test them.